# JavaScript ecma6 change normal function to arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have that code:

```
function defineProperty(object, name, callback){
    if(object.prototype){
        Object.defineProperty(object.prototype, name, {"get": callback});
    }
}
defineProperty(String, "isEmpty", function(){return this.length === 0;});
```

and I use it as below:

```
console.log("".isEmpty, "abc".isEmpty);
```

and it returns:

```
true, false
```

Now, I would like to change function to something like this:

```
defineProperty(String, "isEmptyWithArrow", () => this.length === 0);
```

but "this" refers to Window and I do not know how to change it.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pgx0o29/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot. This impossible. `this` in arrow functions is lexically scoped, that's their outstanding feature. But you *need* a dynamically bound `this`, and that's what `function`s are good for.

If you insist on using fancy new ES6 features, go for a method definition:

```
function defineProperty(object, name, descriptor) {
    if (object.prototype)
        Object.defineProperty(object.prototype, name, descriptor);
}
defineProperty(String, "isEmpty", {get(){return this.length === 0;}, configurable:true});
```

Of course, you could also take a callback that gets the instance as an argument:

```
function defineProperty(object, name, callback) {
    if (object.prototype)
        Object.defineProperty(object.prototype, name, {
            get(){ return callback(this); }, // dynamic this
            configurable: true
        });
}
defineProperty(String, "isEmpty", self => self.length === 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Second code is perfect - it is what I need, really thanks.